# Using JNI in linux, mac and windows

Tags: java, c++, windows, linux, java-native-interface

I have an application completely written in cpp now i need to migrate it in java but i do not need to convert processing logic from cpp to java so i have decided to use JNI. The application must run on linux, mac and windows environment.

But i have found that for windows we need to specify .dll file for jni , for linux .so file and i dont know for mac.

Right now my environment is windows 7.

so my question is :

1. Can i write application such a way that i need to provide any of .dll, .so file for all the three platforms ?
2. How to achieve this ? any guideline ?

Answer (score 0):

In your java class, you will have

System.loadLibrary("foo")

Then you just need a library compiled on each system e.g. libfoo.so for Linux and foo.dll for Windows